# SpringBoot Container - What is diffrence with @Autowired and no @Autowired?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

Maybe the best way to give a question will be to show code below :

```
public class DBConnection {


    private String Host;
    private String username;
    private String password;

    public DBConnection(String Host, String username, String password)
    {
        this.Host = Host;
        this.username = username;
        this.password = password;
    }

    public void addUser(String name)
    {
        System.out.println("add to db");
    }
}
```

And class below :

```
public class UserService {

    public DBConnection dbConnection;

    public UserService(DBConnection dbConnection){

        this.dbConnection = dbConnection;
    }

    public void register()
    {
        dbConnection.addUser("xd");
    }

}
```

And now, why i have to use spring for DI ? I can't see difference between above code and code below (of course in below case i know that in DBConnection i have to use @Component):

```
public class UserService {

    public DBConnection dbConnection;

    @Autowired
    public UserService(DBConnection dbConnection){

        this.dbConnection = dbConnection;
    }

    public void register()
    {
        dbConnection.addUser("xd");
    }

}
```

I can do DI without Spring. What is advantage of using spring Boot?

Comment: The difference is in picking up a book/googling/watching a tutorial - marking down for no research effort

Answer (score 0):

Single constructor is concidered as `@Autowired` by Spring. Then there is no difference.

If there are multiple constructors, then you must mark one of them as `@Autowired` to let Spring know which ctor should be used to instantiate the bean.

Comment: But there is no difference between DI in Spring and no Spring? I use container without spring?

Comment: Im not sure that I got your  question.

Comment: I mean that your code does not give us any information if you are using spring or not

Comment: I want to know, why I have to use Autowired adnotation. Because I can't see difrence between code with Autowired and code without Autowired... What gives me, when I write Autowired above constructor?

Answer (score 0):

Traditionally, Spring always needed `@Autowired` (or the newer `@Inject`) to tell it where to supply dependencies. As of Spring 4.3 (several years ago), if there is exactly one constructor on a class, the Spring container will understand that of course it has to use that constructor and will call it with the necessary dependencies. `@Autowired` is still needed if you have more than one constructor.

You can certainly do DI without a container, and one of the advantages of using constructor injection is that unit testing is simpler because you can inject mock dependencies. However, in actual applications the number of dependencies gets *very* large, and an advantage of a DI container is that it handles the bookkeeping for you. Spring also provides a number of other features, including Web APIs (MVC or WebFlux), AOP services (transactions, retry, tracing), convenient data access (Spring Data projects), automatic configuration (Boot), and more.